# Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу по теме "Арифметика остатков"

Tags: математика, уравнения

Задача:
Найдите все натуральные **`n`** такие, что при делении числа `2023` на **`n`** частное от деления и остаток будут совпадать.

Мои шаги к решению:
Я составила уравнение для лучшего понимания задачи, получила `2023 = n * x + x`, написала программу для получения количества решений этого уравнения. Получила, что решений **`четыре`**, в ручную нашла **`1`** решение (`n=2022, x=1`), но не знаю, почему ответов всего **`4`** (не знаю как доказать) и не нашла остальные три  решения уравнения.

Comment: Вы идете верной дорогой... Теперь сообразите, что 2023 = (n+1)x, и что и n и x целые... а 2023 - это 7\*17²... Дальше все понятно? Не хочется лишать вас радости понимания, так сказать, так что на этом и ограничусь :)

Comment: `n > x`, поэтому решений меньше чем 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже написали, 2023 = (n+1)x и 2023 = 7*17²

Из разложения следует, что делителями 2023 являются 1, 7, 17, 119, 289 и 2023.

Поскольку остаток не может быть больше делителя, n > x.

Решения, получаемые из делителей (значения n): 2022, 288 и 118.

Простейшая переборная программа имеет вид:

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2023; ++i) {
        if (2023 / i == 2023 % i) cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!!

Comment: Вы можете сказать спасибо, щелкая на треугольнике вверх и галочке слева от вопроса.